# Gitlab CI failure but continue to run problem

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

In gitLab, I create CI to build the project, for each stage I have 2 job seperately

```
Build BookProject:
  stage: build  
  <<: *dotnetbuild_job 
  when: manual 
 
Build ShopProject:
  stage: build
  <<: *dotnetbuild_job
  when: manual

Deploy BookProject:
  stage: Deploy 
  needs: ["Build BookProject"]
  <<: *dotnetdeploy_job 
  when: on_success 
 
Deploy ShopProject:
  stage: Deploy
  needs: ["Build ShopProject"]
  <<: *dotnetdeploy_job
  when: on_success
```

I find that when Build BookProject: job return `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`, which the job icon show !, the Deploy BookProject:
are still continue to run, even I set when: on_success, can I know how to prevent it ?

Comment: Exit code 0 is success, so it's expected to move on. If the exit code is unexpectedly 0, we need more information to figure out why. Including your job script and the job output may help.

Comment: sorry , it should be ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: Try adding `allow_failure: false` to your manual build jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When jobs specify `when: manual`, it implies `allow_failure: true`.

To avoid this behavior, specify `allow_failure: false` on your manual build jobs.

Comment: but when I set allow_failure: false, if another job Build ShopProject is not run is that it cannot define as pass ?